# Good texts in Complex numbers?

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, complex-numbers

I have asked some members on chat about good text to study complex numbers , they recommended for example , "Visual Complex Analysis" by Needham and "complex analysis" by Steins.

But, I look for a text for complex numbers not complex analysis (I don't even know what is complex analysis!), Which text do you recommend to study complex numbers ?

I mean, a text covers its properties and its relation to other subject such that Geometry to give the reader Strong background   to use complex numbers in other branches after that, for example prepare the reader to use them in linear algebra or calculus ( special functions for example).

Someone recommended a text named, $\text{"Complex numbers from A to ... Z"}$ by Titu Andreescu & Dorin Andrica, Is it a good text?

Comment: There is a nice intro to complex numbers by someone called Buden. Definitely the one by Andreescu should be good, he trains/trained IMO teams.

Comment: This is the best introduction to complex numbers I've come across so far: http://betterexplained.com/articles/a-visual-intuitive-guide-to-imaginary-numbers/.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: Yes, "Complex numbers from A to ... Z" by Titu Andreescu & Dorin Andrica ***is*** a good text, very fitting if you are interested in understanding complex **numbers**.

In the meantime, you will likely appreciate Paul's Online Math Notes: See his [Complex Numbers Primer](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Extras/ComplexPrimer/ComplexNumbers.aspx). You can study it on-line, and/or download the Primer as a pdf document.

Answer (score 0):

Complex numbers are part of Complex analysis. In fact some countries (like Germany) never teach complex number as a separate topic, there is only complex analysis. In my country complex number was taught separately in high school, no one ever understood what complex numbers are used for.

So your recommendations are absolutely right. I would advise not to learn complex number separately or else you would always be in dilemma why need of complex numbers.